# Yahoo Finance stock ticker only works inside JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, mootools, jsfiddle, yahoo-finance

I am trying to create a JavaScript stock ticker which pulls out live stocks. I have found a working example on JSFiddle which works relatively well and I am trying to integrate the fundamentals into my site.

The code works in JSFiddle but as soon as I take the JavaScript and place it into Dreamweaver there is a syntax error. I think it's fair to say that I am new to JavaScript/AJAX but I have tried understanding the Yahoo API which controls the stock data, which I am now fairly confident with.

Does the code need to link to an external source to work or am I missing something which is preventing me from getting the code to function outside of JSFiddle?

Any help would be appreciated as I have exhausted many hours trying to get this to work.

The code below is also available in [this JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dmzp2r6/).

```
new Request.Stocks({

        display: ['Name', 'Ask', 'Change', 'ChangeinPercent'],

        sortBy: 'Name',

        stocks: ['ABBN.VX', 'ATLN.VX', 'ADEN.VX', 'CSGN.VX', 
                 'HOLN.VX', 'BAER.VX', 'LONN.VX', 'NESN.VX', 
                 'NOVN.VX', 'CFR.VX',  'ROG.VX',  'SGSN.VX',
                 'UHR.VX',  'RUKN.VX', 'SCMN.VX', 'SYNN.VX', 
                 'SYST.VX', 'RIGN.VX', 'UBSN.VX', 'ZURN.VX'],

        onComplete: function(yahoo){
            var result = '';
            Array.each(Array.from(yahoo.query.results.quote), function(quote){
                result += '<h2>{Name}</h2>
                      <p>{Ask} CHF,
                      ChangeinPercent: {ChangeinPercent},
                      Change: {Change}</p>'.substitute(quote);
            }, this);

            $('stocks').set('html', result);
        },

        onRequest: function(script){
            $('stocks').set('text', 'Fetching...');
        }

    }).send();
```

Kind Regards,
Sam

Comment: Your fiddle is using the http://mootools.net/ framework. So you need it to run the code.

Comment: Thankyou I am looking into how to integrate this.

Answer (score 0):

Download the lastest build [here](http://mootools.net/core)

**Note: your js fiddle uses Mootools 1.3.1 i've never used mootools, but if you run into a problem try using this version**

Afterwards, place it in your application folder and link it in your head like so:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="MOOTOOLSLINK"></script>
```